# Run portable LaTeX on Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, executable, latex

I'm trying to get a portable LaTeX installation running on a Gentoo Server. The LaTeX files are already installed.

When I try to run `./pdflatex` in the `path/to/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/` I get the message `exec format error: ./pdflatex`. I'm running the command line with SSH with zsh.

Google told me that this *could* mean that I am using the wrong executable.

But when I run `uname -m` I get `x86_64` so I thought `/x86_64-linux/` contains the correct binaries.

Additionally I have tried all the other LaTeX bins for linux (`i386-linux`, `armel-linux`, `armhf-linux`, `aarch64-linux`) but none of them was working.

When get the contents with `dir` I can also see that there is a `pdflatex` file (link). Also the `ls -l` tells me that the file (which the `pdflatex` links to) has read and execute permissions for all users.

Additionally I have tried all the other LaTeX bins for linux (`i386-linux`, `armel-linux`, `armhf-linux`, `aarch64-linux`) but none of them was working.

**Note**: I do not have root rights so I have to use the protable installation.

How can I run the `pdflatex` command?

Comment: How did you obtain and install Latex in the 1st place?

Comment: I installed them on a virtual kubuntu machine and moved the file to my server. This didn't work so I also installed texlive a second time via SSH. Both times I used the portable version but none of them works. It works on kubuntu though. The installation files were from the official download from [texlive](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)

Comment: Instead if that you should get your admin to install TexLive cleanly for you. Linux is not so great these days when you try to wrestle with it.

Comment: Getting admin rights is not possible. I am using a managed server from an external host. 
But isn't this the reason for offering a portable version? For **not** having to install it and **not** requiring admin rights?

Comment: I don't know. I never used a portable Latex, but what I do know is that TexLive and MikTex work 100% of the time OOB. I run those installations for a living. Google how to get portable to work, as very few actually use that route and you are not likely to see many responses here.

Comment: If you don't have administrative privileges, you can always compile TexLive yourself and specify an installation prefix. Gentoo Prefix enables you to emerge things into your home directory.

Comment: @binki I did not think about that, thank you. I will try to find another solution but if I do not find any I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution for my problem. I'm not sure if this will help anybody else. But just for completeness I post the answer here.

Even though `uname -a` returns `x86_64` I got told that I should use `objdump -a /bin/ls`. This returns `file format elf32-i386`, so the **correct binaries** for me are the **`i386-linux` binaries**.

As I wrote I tested them and they did not work. The problem was that I moved the (pre-installed) files to my server using FTP with **FileZilla**. FileZilla offers a *transfer type*. This is set to *automatically* by default. **Setting** this **to *binary*** explicitly and moving the files to the server again did the trick.

**Now it works**.